# Hyperref - LaTeX - MPlayer - Video issue

Tags: hyperref

### Setting:

I have multiple video players installed on my system e.g. VLC, MPlayer etc etc.

### What am I trying to do?

I am trying to make a presentation using `beamer`, where there would be links to various videos on my system and I would click to play them while presenting. Of course, I do not wish to embed those videos inside my presentation.

### What is the problem?

I wish to use mplayer as the Video player for all the videos. One tex.stackexchange.com page suggested that I use the following command inside a LaTeX file with the `hyperref` package included.

```
\href{run:/usr/local/bin/mplayer -fs VideoFilename.mp4}{Click here}
```

On my computer, this command executes, when I run it from the command line i.e. `mplayer -fs VideoFilename.mp4` works perfectly fine. However, from the PDF it says `File not found`.

In case I use the following command

```
\href(run:VideoFilename.mp4}{Click here}
```

the video runs, but in a different player.

### What I want?

I want the video running fullscreen on MPlayer, when I click from the PDF.

PS: 
The PDF file, the Video File etc are all in the same directory.